# How is multi-dimensional data processed in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am not looking on how to visualize multi-dimensional data, but on what pyplot exactly does when multi-dimensional data is fed to it? As an example, consider this simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[0,2,4]])
Y = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(-1,1)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'ro', alpha=0.3)
```

X is a 3x3 array and Y is a 3x1 array. What I initially thought was happening was that Y would be repeated to match X's dimensions. That is, 3 scatter plots will be produced as X[0] vs Y, X[1] vs Y and X[2] vs Y and all three would be super-imposed on same x-axis. But as from the output below, if my hypothesis was correct, there would be a point at (0,1) from X[2] vs Y graph, but there isn't. Please help me out guys.

[image: Sorry, my repo isn't high enough to post inline images]

Comment: why are you creating the arrays X and Y, but plotting A and B?

Comment: My bad, fixed it now. Originally I had A and B but for better understanding, changed it to X and Y. Overlooked it in the plot command.

Comment: It's `0, 3`, not `0, 1`. Matplotlib plots the columns

Comment: Ya, I got that. Btw, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interpret the result with removing the color specifier for the marker:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[0,2,4]])
Y = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(-1,1)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', alpha=0.3)
```

This will produce the figure below. We see that the blue dots were obtained with the `Y` coordinates and the first element of each array of `X` (namely, `X[:, 0]`), and so on.

[image: multidimensional array and matplotlib]

So `plt.plot` does something similar than

```py
for x in X.T:  # .T for transposing the array
    plt.plot(x, Y, 'o', alpha=0.3)
```

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the answer man. Short and to the point.